# how to imagemagick crop only width

Tags: imagemagick

im trying to crop an image of size 1920x125058 into 900x125058 from the center

so I used `magick convert in.png -crop 900x+510+0 out.png` but this outputs a file of size 900x28800. shouldn't the height be untouched if it is not mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert. For center cropping, use -gravity center

```
magick in.png -gravity center -crop 900x125058+0+0 +repage out.png
```